# Do I need the key to extract a Borg backup from my USB flash drive?

Tags: backup, borg-backup

I backed up some directories in an USB flash drive with [Borg](https://www.borgbackup.org). Right now it only asks me for my passphrase if want to e.g. list the backups.

Will I need the key to extract the backup in a different computer?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how you have initialized your backup repository. If you used "repokey" or "repokey-blake2" as encryption mode, the keyfile will be stored inside the repository and you will only need the passphrase to extract the backup. However, if you used "keyfile" or "keyfile-blake2" you have to provide the keyfile to borg, too.

If you do not remember which encryption mode you have used, you can check using `borg info`:

```
borg info /path/to/repo
```

Comment: If using borgmatic, `borgmatic info` also works.